# crontab 7 days before end of month now kicking off

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, ubuntu-16.04

on Ubuntu 16 my crontab has the following:

```
0 8 20-31 2-12/2 * [ $(date +\%d -d "7 days") == 01 ] && python3 myscript.py &
```

I expected this to kick off this morning but it didn't. It kicked off just fine if changed to:

```
0 8 25 2-12/2 * python3 myscript.py &
```

Any suggestions on how I can crontab to kick off a script 7 days before the end of the month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cronjobs are run by `/bin/sh` by default. Your syntax is not valid for `sh`. Try setting `SHELL=/bin/bash` at the top of your crontab to run all jobs using `bash` instead.